# Preventing ext4 metadata corruption during shutdown

Tags: filesystem, ext4

Recently, I have started getting the "Read-Only File System" error when shutting down the system (Xubuntu 20.04 LTS running on an HP laptop). Rebooting does **not** trigger these corruptions. The laptop has a battery inside which prevents abrupt power failures but only holds for a few minutes so is effectively a UPS.

I wrote a bash script running as a systemd service that cleanly powers off the machine if AC power is lost, but one pattern I've noticed in each of these ext4 corruptions when fixing them with `fsck` is that they all have exactly the same problems:

- Incorrect free block count
- Incorrect free inode count

The HDD inside the laptop has 1 reallocated sector as seen from SMART tests. Replacing the disk is not possible but works properly (for now) otherwise.

I am wondering if there are some preventions I can embed in the bash script to avoid these kind of problems as they appear to be very simple errors that in theory should be preventable.

Comment: This is a symptom of eminent failure, regardless of the SMART data.

Comment: Sounds like you have 2 problems. Why does the battery only last a few mins and the hard drive is failing.

Comment: @David The laptop is quite old and was factory-shipped with Windows XP